# For what purposes is inversion used?

Tags: inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion

While English seems one of the languages most rigid in word order, there are many types of inversion. I know some patterns into which they can be categorized; interrogative sentence, subjunctive mood, negative word comes initial, place comes initial with an indefinite subject, etc. But I don't know why you choose to use inversion when the standard word order is available. It's hard for learners to get it. G rammatical inversions aren't now what I'm asking.

Today I found an inverted sentence I haven't ever seen: "Together can we make our nation come true." This is from https://asgardia.space/en/elections-districts/Japanese and it first looked an influence from Swedish language, which is maybe her native language. How do you get this inversion?
 Natural? Commonplace expression? Would you tell me what's the difference of the nuances from that of the standard word order, though it could be elusive to get the nuance of expression into words?

Comment: Seems like a slogan, written more for impact rather than grammatical correctness. "together" seems to be the main point, so why not say it first?

Comment: @user3169: What about "can we"?

Comment: It's just a mistake by a non-native speaker. Btw, there's no inversion in subjunctive clauses.

Answer (score 1):

I think the inversion of `can` and `we` sounds incorrect and I would consider such usage archaic in English.  In Swedish, it's correct and normal. Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion